# Как более корректно составить регулярку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В строке может встречаться одна из последовательностей:

```
free internal
free stationary
free linear
loaded internal
loaded stationary
loaded linear
```

Между словами может быть один или несколько пробелов. Мне нужно, чтобы  регулярка отлавливала каждую из этих последовательностей.

Я написал так:

`(free\s+internal)|(free\s+stationary)|(free\s+linear)|(loaded\s+internal)|(loaded\s+stationary)|(loaded\s+linear)`

Можно ли это как-то упростить до вида:

`(free|loaded)\s+(internal|stationary|linear)`

??

То есть может быть `free` или `loaded` или оба. А затем должно идти любое из `internal|stationary|linear`

Как записать такую регулярку попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(free|loaded)\s+(internal|stationary|linear)` - это у Вас самая правильная и оптимальная регулярка, в данном случае. Только её ещё нужно в скобки обернуть:

```js
let sTxt = `free internal
free stationary
free linear
loaded internal
loaded stationary
loaded linear`;

let rExp = /((free|loaded)\s+(internal|stationary|linear))/g;

console.log(sTxt.match(rExp));
```

Comment: У меня, как оказалось, в строке нужен был `\\s+`, а не просто `\s+` >_<   Спасибо за помощь))

Comment: Достаточно и `let rExp = /(free|loaded)\s+(internal|stationary|linear)/g;`, лишние скобки не нужны.

Comment: @WiktorStribiew: смотря, где и как использовать. В некоторых случаях удобнее извлекать 1-ю скобочную группу - именно для неё и нужны обобщающие скобки.

Comment: @СергейМишин: да, если регулярка у Вас в кавычках, то нужно экранировать спецсимволы.

Comment: Целое совпадение всегда можно получить по 0 индексу, `sTxt.match(rExp)[0]`. В данном случае внешние собки не нужны.

Comment: @WiktorStribiew: даже, если они избыточны, то никак не мешают. Давайте лучше поищем древние вопросы незакрытые/неотвеченные, да как наотвечаем там. Из комментариев в ответы можно попереносить, раз кому-то лень было ответ писать. Пользы будет больше, чем от скобковой риторики ;-)